# Centering map to marker in else statement

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got following code:

```
var setPresent = false;

[...]

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("getCoordinates"), 'click', function() {
    if(setPresent == false) {
        var coordinatesMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        draggable: true    
        }); 
        setPresent=true;
    } else {
        map.setCenter(coordinatesMarker.getPosition());
        coordinatesMarker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }

  });
```

Marker is added only once, but after this "else" block don't work. What's wrong with else instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you create a local variable in your function, `var coordinatesMarker`, which only survives in response to that first click event.  It's not a global variable.  So when you then click your element again, the else statement gets executed (right?) but it doesn't know what the variable coordinatesMarker is when you try and do `coordinatesMarker.getPosition()`.

One quick way to fix this would be make coordinatesMarker a global variable at the same time as you declare setPresent.  Then in your event listener you're either creating a new marker or updating its coordinates.

Like so:

```
var setPresent = false;
var coordinatesMarker;
[...]

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("getCoordinates"), 'click', function() {
    if(setPresent == false) {
        coordinatesMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        draggable: true    
        }); 
        setPresent=true;
    } else {
        map.setCenter(coordinatesMarker.getPosition());
        coordinatesMarker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }

  });
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to create it on start application. I want to add marker when user clicks button...